# Read Properties file in WEB-INF folder java using init

Tags: java, servlets, properties

I am trying to Read a properties file inside WEB-INF but all I am getting is null. I am completely new to java web development.

My init method:

```
 @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            String path = "";
            path = "/WEB-INF/" + getServletContext().getInitParameter("monpesapropertiesfile");
            String realPath;
            realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(path);
            if(realPath != null){
                 InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(realPath);
                 prop.load(fis);
            }
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public String getDatabaseUrl() {
        String url = prop.getProperty("database.url");
        return url;
    }
```

My Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>monpesapropertiesfile</param-name>
        <param-value>monpesaproperties.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ReadProperty</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.monpesa.properties.ReadProperty</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

I know I must be missing something because the String getDataBaseUrl Returns null. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>monpesapropertiesfile</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/monpesaproperties.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

public void init() throws ServletException {
    try {
        String path = getServletContext().getInitParameter("monpesapropertiesfile");
        final InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path);
        try {
            prop.load(is);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception asd) {
        System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would either

1) put the properties into `WEB-INF/classes` and use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to load it.

or

2) put the full file path into web.xml (and place the file outside of the web application into a user-editable configuration area)